# Canonizing diff-of-the-diffs

Tags: linux, git, diff

My question, in short, is following. (I will explain the rationale later, it's not very relevant to the question itself.) Sometimes, git-diff produces different diffs for the same changeset. It happens, for instance, when there is a large chunk of code that was replaced with a wholly different large chunk of code. Such change, could be expressed in diff terms as "add 2 lines, remove 4 lines, add 5 lines, etc" or "remove 4 lines, add 7 lines, etc". I would like it to be somehow consistent.

The question is how to make the diff canonical, i.e. cause the same change always yield the same diff? From the top of my head -- make the diff "greedy" or something.

The reason it annoys me so much is following. I use much the technique we call "diff-of-the-diffs". (Bear with me if I'm explaining trivial things). After I resolve git rebase conflicts, I produce the unified diff of the old change (i.e. this specific commit in the branch before rebase) and the new change (i.e. current index against HEAD) and then diff these diffs against each other. Such diff-of-the-diffs is amazing as a conflicts resolution sanity check -- you can see right away that a specific conflict was only because of the context change, etc.

Comment: And the question is? How to produce such a beast?

Comment: How many git rebase conflicts do you find yourself resolving, say per month?  Just curious.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Individual conflicts? Like a failed diff chunk? Dozens, if not hundreds.

Comment: @JohnZwinck In our company, there is a policy of rebasing on master before pushing the changes. This way, the history is always linear. In the last 2 months, I've been working on a feature branch of about 40 commits. I rebase it onto the ever-advancing master once or twice a week -- otherwise, the final rebase will be way too painful and I will inevitably screw up somewhere. So, applying 40 commits _always_ causes conflicts.